# Wait for an event before returning

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a function in JavaScript written this way I cannot modify:

```
function doSomething() {
    doFirst();
    (...)
}
```

The first function inside doSomething sends a packet through a WebSocket, and has to wait for a response in order to return. So, in other words, I need doFirst to wait for this response before doing (...).

As a first idea, I thought I could use callbacks to call (...) when doFirst is done, but I can't do this because **I can't write anything on doSomething**, so the following example wouldn't be a possibility at all:

```
function doSomething() {
    doFirst(function() {
        (...)
    });
}
```

So, with this constraint, I have to be able to write something inside doFirst (but once again, not doSomething) to achieve this behaviour.

If I just declare the WebSocket's onmessage callback, (...) gets done before the socket gets the response, and if I use something like:

```
while(!received) { }
```

Of course, the browser hangs and even if I get the response, I'm not able to continue.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I can't write anything on doSomething"*? Are you not able or allowed to change the code in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can do it by promise based and by await operators

.*For more ref*. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

```
function doFirst() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('do first');
        }, 2000);
      });
    }

    async function doSomething() {
     var received =  await doFirst();
       console.log(received);
    }
```

Comment: That just worked! I replaced the timeout, so the socket's callback would resolve the promise, and it just worked, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Poll, like your `while(!received)`, but with a sleep so the eventloop allows for other instructions in between. I.e.:

```
const checkInterval = setInterval(function(){
  if(!received) return;
  clearInterval(checkInterval);
  //do your stuff here
}, 10)
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but won't doFirst return anyway if I do this? I need the function to "wait", then return and proceed just when the packet arrived.

Comment: Make doFirst a promise and `resolve` it in the '//do stuff here'

Answer (score 0):

I think a traditional solution of `flag` usage would be useful. You could initiate a variable `flag=False` outside of `doSomething()` or `doFirst()` and make it `flag=True` when you get your response.

Comment: This is what I'm doing, actually. There is the received flag, that is set true when the packet arrives. But the `while(!received) { }` hangs the page and I assume it cannot call the onmessage callback from the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Just another "possible" approach, here is a Promise based one, which still relies on an interval, but isolates the rest of the code.

```
var _onceReceived = function(timeoutSeverity) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var _mInterval = setInterval(function(){
      if (received !== null && received !== undefined) {
        clearInterval(_mInterval);
        resolve(received);
      }
    }, timeoutSeverity);
  });
}
```

basically, this will look for the variable received and check whether it's valid or not, allowing you to set a custom timeout according to a desired severity.

Sample usage:

```
_onceReceived(1000).then(function(res){
    alert('received was now set, and it is: ' + res);
});
```

Full sample:

```
var received;
function doesSomething() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        received = 10;      
  }, 5000);
}

var _onceReceived = function(timeoutSeverity) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var _mInterval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('checking!');
      if (received !== null && received !== undefined) {
        clearInterval(_mInterval);
        resolve(received);
      }
    }, timeoutSeverity);
  });
}

doesSomething();
_onceReceived(1000).then(function(res){
    alert('received was now set, and it is: ' + res);
});
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1zs5vcw/1/

Comment: I imagined this Promise thing could help, but unfortunately I don't get the concept yet, and thus I don't know how to implement what you suggested to me. Anyway, the solution I'm looking for involves not touching the main doSomething function, and not letting doFirst return until the packet arrives, because I don't want the program to keep running if I don't have that. I don't know if your solution does what I'm looking for or not, so I'm really sorry, I'll try to learn some promises to see if I can work it out. Thank you!

Comment: @LucianoMarti Promises were made to work with asyncronous code: in your case, it's not needed, but it's a good approach to isolate the rest of the code from the "async" logic. The example shows a generic scenario, you can easily apply that to your own scenario by ignoring the "doesSomething" function.